# How to limit fields in Form Django 2.2?

Tags: django, django-forms

I got problem on limiting field shown in forms.ModelForm.

I Use Django 2.2

Currently I have

models.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model) :
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    justchar = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
```

admins.py

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin) :
    form=MyModelForm

admin.site.register(MyModel,MyModelAdmin)
```

form.py

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm) :
    class Meta:
        fields = ['user']
```

But the form still shows all fields.
I also tried with 'exclude', but got same results

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a form for this. In fact, as the admin docs [explicitly state](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form), the `fields` attribute on a modelform is ignored in the admin.

Instead, just set [`fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fields) directly on the admin class:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin) :
    fields = ['user']

admin.site.register(MyModel,MyModelAdmin)
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response. But I want different fields between change and add.